# How to match multiple values in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, match

I would like to know how I can match multiple values in an array.

For example:

```
int set[7] = {1,3,5,7,9,11,42};

int new_array[7];

for(int i =0;i<7;i++)
   scanf("%d",&*(new_array + i));

for(int i=0;i<7;i++)


if(new_array[i] matches 5 numbers in set[i])// let's say numbers entered match 5 numbers in the set array

   do something;
```

Comment: It's unclear what part you're missing/asking? You don't have the code for reading in new_array, nor the comparison. Are you asking for the intersection of the two arrays to be of a minimum length (5 in this example)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, so I want to enter 7 numbers and check them against the array of set values and if lets say numbers entered exist in the array in any position i want it to print them

Comment: you need a double for loop and a counter .. if I understood the question

Comment: ok thanks and how do i implement it ? why do i need the counter? Basically i need to match entered numbers with the numbers in the array called set

Comment: You need the counter to know *how many* numbers are matched (so that you have at least, say, 5 matches). There is no `if` statement in C like the one you want. Try and implement that double for loop and come back if that causes problems.

Comment: thanks I actually did it ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find(int n , int array[n], int value){
    //array is sorted in ascending order
    int low = 0, high = n - 1;
    while(low <= high){
        int mid = (low + high)/2;
        if(array[mid] == value)
            return mid;
        if(array[mid] < value)
            low = mid + 1;
        else
            high = mid - 1;
    }
    return -1;//not found
}

int main(){
    int set[7] = {1,3,5,7,9,11,42};
    int new_array[7];
    int match[7], mcount=0;

    for(int i =0;i<7;i++){
        scanf("%d", &new_array[i]);
        if(find(7, set, new_array[i]) != -1){
            match[mcount++] = new_array[i];
        }
    }
    if(mcount >=5)
        //do something;
        for(int i=0;i<mcount;++i)
            printf("%d ", match[i]);
    return 0;
}
```